# How to remove mutable array element from NSUserdefaults?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, nsuserdefaults

I store array element in `NSUserdefault` and retrive from this but I want to remove array element from `NSUserdefault`.

**retriving from NSuserdefault**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let array = defaults.object(forKey: "ArrayString") as? [String] ?? [String]()
print("NSUserDefault :\(array)")
```

**Result:**

```
NSUserDefault :["first", "second","third","fourth","fifth"]
```

I display this array in `CollectionView` now I want to remove from this array how?

**Thank You in Advance..**

Comment: you want to remove element from array or remove array object from userdefaults?

Comment: You just need to save the whole array back to NSUserDefaults once you have removed the element you want.

Comment: thank you @Michael but i want to display this array as favourite in collectionview ,user can remove from collectionview than how?

Comment: @seggy Can you show the code of collectionView, how you are deleting object from array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want - are you trying to load the 5 from NSUserDefaults, display 5 in a CollectionView, update NSUserDefaults to now only have 4, but still display 5 in CollectionView? If so, just copy the 5 to another array, remove the one you don't want, and save it to NSUserDefaults, overwriting the original. The CollectionView will still reference the original array of 5.

Comment: Thank you @NiravD i remove element from array successfully ,problem in NSUserdefault not in array.

Comment: yupp i solved this.... i will update answer asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Swift 2.x

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("MyKey")
```

#### Swift 3.0

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "MyKey")
```

Comment: thank you @Chandresh Kachariya but please read my question carefully i wanna remove element not key.

Answer (score 2):

We can remove element from `NSUserdefault` see this...

**---> Self Solution and Helpful for me...**

**Store array in NSUserdefault**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(appDelegate.arrMutable, forKey: "ArrayString")
defaults.synchronize()
```

**Retrieving from NSUserdefault**

```
var array : Array<String> = []
array  = defaults.object(forKey: "ArrayString") as? [String] ?? [String]()
```

**Remove array element from NSUserdefault**

```
array.remove(at: buttonIndex)
defaults.set(array, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
defaults.synchronize()
print("Removed Array:\(array)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete item from array and then again save the same array in UserDefaults, under the same key. It will overwrite original.

This is example from tableView:

```
itemArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
UserDefaults.standard.set(itemArray, forKey: "itemArray")
```